# MS Dynamics CRM 2011: Unexpected error in Audit History upon deleting user team

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

We have an issue with an unexpected error in the audit history of contacts. The error appears since we have deleted a user team from the system.

Tracing the error delivers the message: "Crm Exception: Message: team With Id = b14b1a72-... Does Not Exist"

The auditbase table contains a row with the team id in the field "change data" for the contacts. Update rollup of CRM server is 11.

At the moment we see two possibilities:
- Restoring the teams out of a backup: single data rows have to be restored.
- "hard deleting" the affect rows from table auditbase: critical?

Are there any other ideas or hints? Has anyone already deleted entries from the audit table?

Thanks in advance

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have solved this issue by updating the affected rows via SQL statement. We set the change data entry to an existing team GUID. The audit history is displayed without an error message again. All affected audit entries where share/unshare operations (action type 48, 49) for the deleted teams on the contacts.

It remains unsettled how this could even happen. Deleting an object should also delete the corresponding audit history entries, especially when they are referenced.

Regards
Alex